# What is the best way to see if a group of items is placed within a specific part of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization

(See example below to fully understand what I'm asking)

I have an array of items that I will put other items into and remove items out of depending on user choices. This array always has an "active set" of contiguous items of no more than 30 items (and it's only less than 30 when the total set of items is less than 30, otherwise, it must be full). The user can change the start of the active set.

What I want to know is what's the "cleanest" code, and most efficient way to check if new items added-to/removed-from the list fall within the active set, either in part or whole? (Also, if there are currently 10 total items, thus making the active set items 0-9, and they add 10 items in front of item 0 - which makes item 0 become item 10 - then I want to be able to know to change the active set to the new item 0 till item 19)

EXAMPLE:

```
//For this example, I'm making the active set be 10 items so I can write less
var activeSetLength = 10;

//The total set
var allItems = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o" ];

//First item in active set (in this example, this makes "m" the last active item)
var activeSet = allItems.slice( 3, 3 + activeSetLength );

/*
 * Now imagine the user is trying to add items into our list, how best do I handle
 * figuring out whether to add them to the activeset list?.
 */
//Adding items into list at position 1 (so only some of these will now be in the active set)
addItems( [ "one", "two", "three", "four" ], 1 );
```

Please let me know if you need more explanation as this may not be the clearest question. Thanks!

**NOTE: In the "real world" my activeSet is implemented as a DOM node so the items are changed in it via appendChild/insertBefore/removeChild** (this note added for clarification)

Comment: After adding items, can't you just reassign your activeSet variable?

Comment: @Brian No, in the "real world", my active set is actually a DOM Node. So I need to actually appendChild/insertBefore/removeChild to change the nodes inside of it. (I didn't include that info because I thought it would add complexity that distracts from the actual question, sorry)

Comment: Do you use jquery? You can add and remove class attributes to the DOM nodes with javascript to keep track of which ones are active.

Comment: I guess this is not really an array.  You can't index each item by an integer correct?

Comment: Since you can create and remove DOM nodes with javascript, another possible solution would be to to just remove all "activeSet" nodes, and then recreate a new list of "activeSet" nodes when items are added.

Comment: No, adding/removing full groups will cause too much lag and the dom node to clear out instead of changing instantly. Also, the dom node holds lots of other stuff too so just looping through the child nodes in it won't work. This is why i have an actual array of all items and keep track of the active items in the items array.

Comment: Here's my idea: at beginning of addItems(), take a "snapshot" via allItems.slice(...), then add the new items, take another snapshot of current lines in active set, then compare those two small arrays and add/insert/remove as needed. Does this make sense?

Comment: Without reading too deeply into your question, it seems weird to me that you jump directly into assuming this is an array.  Are other data structures an option?  For example, with a hash table or balanced search tree you could determine set membership quickly without compromising speed of insertion and removal.

Comment: Hash tables in javascript are buggy (I've had cases where I named a key with something that was somehow used by Firefox under the hood, with no documentation and caused issues) and MUCH slower than straight arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a snapshot before/after to handle the comparison and did something along these lines:

```
addItems: function(items, insertAt)
{
    //The current items in the active set as an array
    var snapshot = this.getSnapshot();

    //Add to items array at position indicated
    this.saveItems( items, insertAt );

    //Change the items in active set
    this.updateActiveSet( snapshot );
}

updateActiveSet: function(oldSnapshot)
{
    //Take a new snapshot
    var currentSnapshot = this.getSnapshot();

    //Last dealt with item's index
    var lastHandled = -1;

    for ( var i = 0, length = oldSnapshot.length; i < length; i++ )
    {
        var old = oldSnapshot[ i ];
        var indexInCurrent = currentSnapshot.indexOf( old );

        //This item is still in the active set
        if ( indexInCurrent != -1 )
        {
            //We need to insert all current items before this
            for ( var iNew = lastHandled + 1; iNew < indexInCurrent; iNew++ ) activeSet.insertBefore( currentSnapshot[ iNew ], old );

            //Update last handled
            lastHandled = indexInCurrent;
        }

        //Remove from active set dom
        else activeSet.removeChild( old );
    }

    //Now append all new items that weren't inserted before a remaining item
    for ( var i = lastHandled + 1, length = currentSnapshot.length; i < length; i++ ) activeSet.appendChild( currentSnapshot[ i ] );
}

getSnapshot: function()
{
    return this.allItems.slice( this.startOfActiveSet, this.startOfActiveSet + this.activeSetLength );
}
```